# Ошибка в программе на циклический сдвиг

Tags: c

Задача считать строку текста из файла и циклически сдвигать её влево на три позиции (и записывать в другой файл). Но при записи появляются символы "я".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[200], c;
    int i = 0, j, k, curMove = 3;
    FILE* aa, * bb;
    fopen_s(&aa, "//Mac/Home/Desktop/laba4_5/problem_no_2/aa.txt", "r");
    fopen_s(&bb, "//Mac/Home/Desktop/laba4_5/problem_no_2/bb.txt", "w");
    c = fgetc(aa);
    while (c != EOF) {
        k = 0;
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
            str[i] = c;
            i++;
            c = fgetc(aa);
            k++;
        }

        j = curMove%k;
        while (j < k) {
            fputc(c, bb);
            j++;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < curMove % k; j++)
            fputc(c, bb);
            
        
    }
    fclose(aa);
    fclose(bb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (в частности: не надо всё содержимое вопроса пытаться запихнуть в его заголовок).

Comment: Вам нужно считать строку fgets и только потом работать с массивом, циклически сдвигая его и записывать в файл :) Это НАПИСАНО у вас в задаче :) EOF наврятли вы получите в c!(есть функция feof) EOF = End Of File. Есть еще EOL (End Of Line) что в основном в файлах как 0D0A (0D(13)=перевод строки, 0A(10)=возврат каретки). Т.е. в ваш str[200] будет выглядеть примерно так, после считывания fgets. &str0[Это текст считанный из файла0D0A] остальные символы до конца в str нули(0). Далее делайте остальные действия.

Comment: fgetc = File Get Char (1 символ считать) а fgets = File Get String (считать строку). fgets считывает до 0d0a (включительно)

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что

```
c = fgetc(aa);
```

`c` у вас `char`, а значит, вы никак не отличите `EOF`, который в `char` не должен влезать по определению, от `char` наподобие `я`.

Потом, вы выводить пытаетесь **один и тот же символ**

```
fputc(c, bb);
```

а не символы строки...

Начните с исправления этих ошибок.

Comment: спасибо, сам я почему-то даже этого не замечал

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы считываете данные из файла построчно в массив **str** Но потом этот массив не используете. А пишите в файл, значение из переменной **c**. А по логике там у вас символ конца файла. Он и даёт "я".
2. Конструкция `j = curMove%k;` очень странная. Вы получаете остаток от деления числа 3 (которое в **curMove**) на длину строки, которую посчитали в **k**. Для всех случаев когда строка длинее чем 3 символа **j** будет равняться 3. По сути данная операция и не нужна наверное. Как и переменная **curMove**
3. Есть еще сомнения во вложенности циклов while - но в общем-то такая конструкция должна работать более или менее нормально.
4. И наверное оптимальнее было бы считывать сразу строку, и уже с ней работать. Считывание и запись файлов посимвольно - не очень оптимально.